# Arithmetic operations dynamically to a method in android?

Tags: java, math, collections, hashmap, operators

I want to perform Arithmetic operations(only additions and subtraction) dynamically , i am having a json which includes the operation like below 
 **"operation": "a+b"** this key value is my operation and this is dynamically means it will also comes like **"operation": "a+b+d-c+e"** but one this is sure that it will only comes with additions and subtraction

and my values are in **Hashmap** like

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("a", "10");
map.put("b", "10");
map.put("c", "5");
map.put("d", "5");
map.put("e", "15");


[
    {
        "id": 15,
        "lable": "C__a_plus_b",
        "field": "b",
        "operator": "None",
        "inputType": "Number",
        "ids": "13",
        "operation": "a+b",
        "operations": "true"
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "lable": "F__c_plus_d",
        "field": "d",
        "operator": "None",
        "inputType": "Number",
        "ids": "17",
        "operation": "C__a_plus_b+d",
        "operations": "true"
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "lable": "d_c_f",
        "field": "F__c_plus_d",
        "operator": "None",
        "inputType": "Number",
        "ids": "19",
        "operation": "d+C__a_plus_b-F__c_plus_d",
        "operations": "true"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are going to implement is called *interpreter*. Interpreter is a program which simulates a computer. The first thing you have to think about a computer, be it implemented in hardware or software, is *instruction set*. Read some literature about this to learn what kinds of instruction sets exist.

Then, looking at the sample of input code you provided, I have to admit that it is a very bad format of an instruction set. In a good instruction set, each instruction has distinct fields for operands and operation code. Here we can see that only one operand is provided as a field of instruction data structure ("field": "b" in the first instruction) and so is useless, field "operator" says always "None" and also is useless, and all information has to be retrieved from the field "operation", whose value is a text. So, you have also to implement a *Parser* which, given an input string like `"d+C__a_plus_b-F__c_plus_d"`, returns a data structure like this:

```
{"operator":"-",
 "leftOperand":
    {"operator:"+",
     "leftOperand":"d",
     "rightOperand":"C__a_plus_b"
    },
 "rightOperand":"F__c_plus_d"
}
```

I used JSON/Javasript representation, but it can be represented in any programming language, e.g. Java.

The topic how to implement parsers is described elsewhere and I will not explain it here.

In fact, instead of producing the data structure, the parser can immediately calculate and return the value of the input expression - I only stress that it is still a parser rather than an interpreter.